# How to correct invalid HTML from WebBrowser Control?

Tags: html, xml, winforms, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

I am using a WebBrowser Control as a text editor. After the user has entered or edited some text and closes the editor, I parse the content of the attribute `webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml` to create some text-objects for another application.

However the parser only works with valid HTML, as I thought, the WebBrowser Control would produce only valid HTML. Unfortunately with some copying and pasting within the editor I was able to produce the following HTML:

```
<BODY {...some Attributes...}>
    <P align=left>
        <FONT size=7>
            some text
            <FONT color=#00b700>
                more text
            </FONT>
            <FONT color=#ff0000>
                text
                <FONT size=7>
                    text
                    <FONT color=#00b700>
                        text
                    </FONT>
                    <FONT color=#ff0000>
                        text
                    </FONT>
                </FONT>
            </P>
        </FONT>
    </FONT>
</BODY>
```

As you can see, the closing p-Tag seems to be swapped with a closing font-Tag. In the WebBrowser Control everything looks fine, but the parser I wrote can´t handle the HTML. (In the parser I extract all text-Nodes and from each one I climb up the DOM-tree till I reach the body-Node, looking for text-formatting along the way). Also HtmlAgilityPack says the InnerHtml of the p-Node is empty.

Is there some magic way to autocorrect "slightly" invalid HTML?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to correct the html. What do you need to extract from the html?

Comment: @Reza: my parsing and also HtmlAgilityPack depends on valid Html. But I found a solution, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further searching I found [http://corsis.sourceforge.net/index.php/Html2Xhtml](http://corsis.sourceforge.net/index.php/Html2Xhtm%20%22Html2Xhtml%22l)

Works like a charm and does exactly what I need to be done:

Html from WebBrowser Control:

```
<BODY >
    <P align=left>
        <FONT size=7>
            11111&nbsp;2222
            <FONT color=#00b700>

            </FONT>
            <FONT color=#ff0000>
                ?????
                <FONT size=7>
                    11111&nbsp;2222
                    <FONT color=#00b700>

                    </FONT>
                    <FONT color=#ff0000>
                        ?????
                    </FONT>
                </FONT>
            </P>
        </FONT>
    </FONT>
</BODY>
```

Corrected with Html2Xhtml:

```
<body>
    <p align=\"left\">
        <font size=\"7\">
            11111&nbsp;2222
            <font color=\"#00b700\">

            </font>
            <font color=\"#ff0000\">
                ????? 
                <font size=\"7\">
                    11111&nbsp;2222
                    <font color=\"#00b700\">

                    </font>
                    <font color=\"#ff0000\">
                        ?????
                    </font>
                </font>
            </font>
        </font>
    </p>
</body>
```

Amazing!

Comment: Good job, but maybe you even don't need that if you only want to find some tag.